# Strange Saving Behaviour of Samsung's "Write on PDF"

Tags: samsung, pdf, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

I did some work yesterday using `Write on PDF` on my `Samsung S6 Lite` tablet. Come this morning, and it didn't save. Bit of a nightmare. Anyway, I redid the work, but decided this afternoon to test out exactly how the saving works. It behaves very strangely!

I have uploaded a video (screen capture) to YouTube showing exactly the behaviour: https://youtu.be/ksfVwWm6iUY.

Basically, when I open with `Write on PDF`, it doesn't seem to save successfully. Instead, I need download it, open it up and write on it before saving. Even then, it saves some random stuff. The video hopefully makes this clear.

> I want to open a PDF from a webpage (or app) in `Write on PDF`, do some writing on it, then save.
> How do I get this to *actually save*?

Comment: I would try to use a local PDF file, not one that is saved in Dropbox.

Comment: Sure. The point is to not have to download the file then open it with `Write to PDF` when there is the option there immediately. As you can see in the video, it clearly says `Saved in Device Storage/Write on PDF` (around the 29/30sec mark). I don't know why it saves without the annotations...